# How do I convert [][]byte to []byte?

Tags: go, byte, slice

I have a function which splits data and returns slice of subslices:

```
(buf []byte, lim int) [][]byte
```

Obviously I get an error if I do:

```
n, err = out.Write(split(buf[:n], 100))
```

The error:

> cannot convert split(buf[:n], 100) (type [][]byte) to type []byte

How do I convert `[][]byte` to `[]byte`?

Edit based on @Wishwa Perera: https://play.golang.org/p/nApPAYRV4ZW

Comment: can you show the implementation of the split function

Comment: This question basically comes down to how to concatenate 2 slices. I'm pretty sure you can find plenty of examples of how to do that all over the internet.

Comment: @WishwaPerera question updated!

Comment: @super this is a great hint, thanks!

Comment: Like this `func(in [][]byte) []byte { return nil }`. Works well and is dead fast. Tip: You asked the wrong question. It's better to ask what data you have and what you want and how the want is composed of / computed from the have. An example typically helps.

Comment: @hyogy since you are splitting the `buf` into `chunks`, why don't you pass the individual chunks to `Write` by looping over the result of `split`?

Comment: @mkopriva can you please show what you say on https://play.golang.org/?(:

Comment: @hyogy https://play.golang.org/p/kfNjDWfCCJ6

Comment: @mkopriva copy your last comment and post an answer, you solved even what I did not ask for (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are splitting `buf` into `chunks`, you can pass them individually to `Write` by looping over the result of `split`.

```golang
for _, chunk := range split(buf[:n], 100) {
    if _, err := out.Write(chunk); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `out` is a `net.Conn` as in your other question, then use [net.Buffers](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Buffers) to write the `[][]byte`.

```
b := net.Buffers(split(buf[:n], 100))
_, err := b.WriteTo(out)
if err != nil {
   panic(err)
}
```